# Type guards on string literals to refine a union type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use a union type with string literals, an I was expecting to be able to refine the type using ==:

```
class Color {
    constructor(public r: number, public g: number, public b: number) {
    }
}

interface NodeProperties {
    fill?: 'none' | Color;
}

var n: NodeProperties = { fill: new Color(0, 0, 0) };

if (n.fill && n.fill !== 'none') {
    console.log(n.fill.r);
}
```

However, Typescript believes the n.fill in the console.log line is of type `Color | 'none'`. Is this expected? Is the only way to refine this type to use `n.fill instanceof Color`?

On a related question, when I did it slightly different I got a different error:

```
class Color {
    constructor(public r: number, public g: number, public b: number) {
    }
}

type Foo = 'none' | Color;

var f: Foo = new Color(0, 0, 0);

if (f !== 'none') {
    console.log(f.r);
}
```

Here I get the error that the !== operator can not be applied to types Color and string. Why am I getting this error when using !== on a bare variable but not when I'm using it in a member of an object?

Comment: This is supported in TypeScript 2.0 by [tagged union types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#tagged-union-types)

Comment: While tagged union types seems another way to do what I want to do, just using a string literal in the union looks like a less bloated way to achieve the same result in this case (no need for an extra interface). Anyway, thanks for the reference, I may end up switching my final code to tagged union types.

Comment: Your first example [is valid with TS 2.0](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Color%20{%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%28public%20r%3A%20number%2C%20public%20g%3A%20number%2C%20public%20b%3A%20number%29%20{%0D%0A%20%20%20%20}%0D%0A}%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20NodeProperties%20{%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fill%3F%3A%20%27none%27%20|%20Color%3B%0D%0A}%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20n%3A%20NodeProperties%20%3D%20{%20fill%3A%20new%20Color%280%2C%200%2C%200%29%20}%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20%28n.fill%20%26%26%20n.fill%20!%3D%3D%20%27none%27%29%20{%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log%28n.fill.r%29%3B%0D%0A}).

Comment: I was getting the error and I described with TS 2.0.0, but it works with TS 2.0.3. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe your second example is a bug of TS 2.0.3 and [should be reported](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/)?

Comment: The `n.fill !== 'none'` is interpreted like a tagged union, almost as if you had a union between `NodeProperties { fill: 'none' }` and `NodeProperties { fill: Color }`, once you rule out `fill === 'none'` all that is left is for it to be a color. Though I find it odd that your second example doesn't work in TS 2.0 either. I guess since its not a class the rules for tagged unions do not kick in. Though it begs the question, was this intended behaviour according to the spec or accidental in the implementation.

Comment: I filed a bug report (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11277). Paleo or Chris, if you can fill an answer stating that the first example has been fixed in 2.0.3 and that the second looks like a bug I will accept it. Thank you both!

Comment: My thoughts were the reverse, it might be the first is a bug and wasn't intended, since the notes on tagged unions say they're only supposed to support string union types.